# Vim/Evil keybindings in Magit 2.1

Tags: key-bindings, magit, evil

I love vim keybindings. For older versions of Magit, I used this to allow <kbd>j</kbd>/<kbd>k</kbd> scrolling:

```el
(define-key magit-status-mode-map (kbd "k") #'previous-line)
(define-key magit-status-mode-map (kbd "K") #'magit-discard-item)
(define-key magit-status-mode-map (kbd "j") #'next-line)
```

But now, of course, the keymaps have changed. I have a sort of hacked up solution that loops through all the keymaps, but it's quite complicated and brittle.

Is there any easy way to customize keybindings in `magit`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have the same issue (and I am the maintainer :-), and I'm afraid there's no completely trivial fix. (I don't use vim bindings, but I use <kbd>C-{jikl}</kbd> for character/line navigation, and in Magit <kbd>i</kbd> and <kbd>k</kbd> to go up/down a section.

To reproduce your old customizations you could do this:

```
(define-key magit-mode-map (kbd "k") #'previous-line)
(define-key magit-mode-map (kbd "K") #'magit-discard)
(define-key magit-mode-map (kbd "j") #'next-line)
```

And then search for `"k"` (<kbd>M-x rgrep RET "K" RET *.el RET</kbd>). Finally add for each found match:

```
(define-key KEYMAP (kbd "k") #'previous-line)
(define-key KEYMAP (kbd "K") COMMAND)
```

Comment: Okay, cool. I have a macro that generates all of the bindings for the various maps, so I think I'll be good, then.